# How to keep the last row at the bottom of the table that has a minimum height for the body,

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to design an invoice table using html and css.
The rows are added dynamically added. The body of the table should have a minimum height to accommodate say around 5-6 rows after which the table body should extend based on the rows. While trying to achieve this, I can't get the last row which contains the Totals to go at the bottom of the table. And also can't set the minimum height for the body.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered border-dark border-2">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">S No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">HSN Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
            <th scope="col">Uom</th>
            <th scope="col">Rate</th>
            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
            <th scope="col">Taxable Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">GST %</th>
            <th scope="col">IGST Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">CGST Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">SGST Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="item-table">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
<--    Dynamically entered rows -->
      </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr class="fw-bold">
              <td></td>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Total Qty</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Total Discount</td>
              <td>Total Amount</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

This is my desired output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really do it in the way you describe. If you set a height or a minimum height for the table, the rows which do exist will just stretch to divide that space between them.

You could get close, though, by adding a blank **spacer row** with a specified height at the end of your `<tbody>` (instead of setting a height or a minimum height on the `<table>`).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
th, tfoot td, td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th, tfoot td {
  background: #eee;
}
tr.spacer {
  height: 12em;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">S No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">HSN Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
            <th scope="col">Uom</th>
            <th scope="col">Rate</th>
            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
            <th scope="col">Taxable Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">GST %</th>
            <th scope="col">IGST Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">CGST Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">SGST Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="item-table">
          <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
          <tr class="spacer">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr class="fw-bold">
              <td></td>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Total Qty</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Total Discount</td>
              <td>Total Amount</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to control the height of the spacer row based on the number of rows?

Comment: Sure, if you are creating rows dynamically then you must know how many rows there are, so you can use an inline style to specify the height of the spacer row accordingly.